# Parse strange Date String?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

i'm actually working on a project which scans PDFs. On those PDFs there are dates, but it seems to be more complicated than usual because it's a French date and the format may varies (month is 3/4 letters), example :

> MERMAR17 - LUNJUIL14 ...

And, I want the following output :

> 17/03 - 14/07 ...

My code sample :

```
String date = "MARJUIN2" 
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE'MMM'dd", Locale.FRENCH);
        try {
            Date varDate = dateFormat.parse(date);         
            cellString = varDate.toString();
            SimpleDateFormat newDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.FRENCH);
            cellString = newDF.format(varDate);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Is it possible ? Or n/ ?

Comment: Equivalent to THUJUNE2

Comment: french date, corresponding to 'MARdi JUIN' which mean tuesday, june basically

Comment: Is day of week necessary? `date.substring(3)` before parsing?

Comment: Day of week not necessary :) but still stuck with or w/ this

Comment: Well, what is your output? And why did you put the single quotes in the format?

Comment: Do you get an exception for that code?

Comment: You could also do this by parsing it manually (take the first 3 letters and the other 3 or 4 letters, and lookup which day and month they are). You don't *have* to use `SimpleDateFormat` if it's hard to get it to do what you want.

Comment: Can you use Java-8? Or are you open for a third-party-library? With `SimpleDateFormat` it is nigh to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here a solution without Java-8 or any external library (although it would be easier). The solution is based on the assumption that your input always starts with day-names whose length is always fixed to be 3 chars ("MER", "LUN" etc). And the solution takes into account a possible leap day Feb-29 by choosing the default year to be 2000.

You may ask why so much effort. Well, the reason is that **the text resources you have deviate from those in JDK (or in CLDR). So you must set up your own specialized text resources.** The month names I used in the solution are only guess-work. You should adjust these names to your needs.

```
static final String[] MONTHS =
    { "JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "AVR", "MAI", "JUIN", "JUIL", "AOÛ", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String s = "MERMAR17 - LUNJUIL14";
    String[] parts = s.split(" - ");

    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEMMMdd yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
    System.out.println(parser.format(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 2, 18).getTime()));
    // shows deviation between your input and JDK-resources: mer.mars18 2015

    int m0 = parse(parts[0]);
    int m1 = parse(parts[1]);
    Date d0 =
        new GregorianCalendar(
            2000,
            m0,
            Integer.parseInt(parts[0].substring(3 + MONTHS[m0].length()))
        ).getTime();
    Date d1 =
        new GregorianCalendar(
            2000,
            m1,
            Integer.parseInt(parts[1].substring(3 + MONTHS[m1].length()))
        ).getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
    String result = format.format(d0) + " - " + format.format(d1);
    System.out.println(result); // 17/03 - 14/07

}

private static int parse(String input) throws ParseException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (input.substring(3).startsWith(MONTHS[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new ParseException("Cannot parse month abbreviation in: " + input, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, I just need some improvements (some inputs contains 'MERJUIL1er' etc..